# Prove that for any sets A and B there is a unique set C such that A $\Delta$ C = B

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

**Prove that for any sets A and B there is a unique set C such that A $\Delta$ C = B**

Existence: Suppose A and B are arbitrary sets. Suppose C = A $\Delta$ B. Then A $\Delta$ C = A $\Delta$ (A $\Delta$ B) = (A $\Delta$ A) $\Delta$B = $\varnothing$ $\Delta$ B = B.

Uniqueness: Suppose C$_1$ and C$_2$ are two arbitrary sets such that A $\Delta$ C$_1$ = B and A $\Delta$ C$_2$ = B. Thus A $\Delta$ C$_1$ = A $\Delta$ C$_2$. Suppose   x$\in$ C$_1$. Thus we have two cases.

Case 1: x $\in$ C$_1$\A. Thus x $\in$ A $\Delta$ C$_1$ and x $\in$ A $\Delta$ C$_2$. Since x $\notin$ A, x $\in$ C$_2$.

Case 2: x $\in$ C$_1$ $\land$ x $\in$ A. Thus x $\notin$ C$_1$ $\Delta$ A and x $\notin$ C$_2$ $\Delta$ A. Since x $\in$ A, x $\in$ C$_2$.

Thus, C$_1$ $\subseteq$ C$_2$. Similar reasoning can be used to show C$_2$ $\subseteq$ C$_1$ and therefore C$_1$ = C$_2$. Therefore C is unique.

Is my reasoning for uniqueness valid? I have seen some suppose some set, say C', and let A = C' $\Delta$ B. Thus A $\Delta$ B = (C' $\Delta$ B) $\Delta$ B = C' (B $\Delta$ B) = C $\Delta$ $\varnothing$ = C. Thus C' = A $\Delta$ B = C. This seems unreasonable as A has already been assumed to be arbitrary and we are now stating it to be a particular set. The uniqueness proof comes after assuming A and B.

Comment: Since you already know that $\triangle$ is associative, the uniqueness part can be shortened.  If $A\triangle C_1=A\triangle C_2$, then $$C_1=A\triangle(A\triangle C_1)=A\triangle(A\triangle C_2)=C_2\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks for this- I assume then that the uniqueness piece is fine, if not a little drawn-out.

Comment: For uniqueness why don't you just say if $A\Delta C=B$ then $$A\Delta(A\Delta C)=A\Delta B$$ $$A\Delta(A\Delta C)=(A\Delta A)\Delta C=\emptyset\Delta C=C$$ $$C=A\Delta B$$

Comment: Your original argument is fine.  I would give you full credit, if I were your grader.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is fine, though like Batominovski (in the comments) I would prove uniqueness after assuming that $A\triangle C_1=A\triangle C_2$ by the calculation

$$\begin{align*}
C_1&=\varnothing\triangle C_1=(A\triangle A)\triangle C_1=A\triangle(A\triangle C_1)\\
&=A\triangle(A\triangle C_2)=(A\triangle A)\triangle C_2=\varnothing\triangle C_2=C_2
\end{align*}$$

rather than by ‘element-chasing’.

The argument that you discuss in your last paragraph is a very poorly stated version of a perfectly legitimate argument that goes like this. Suppose that $A\triangle C=B$ and $A\triangle C'=B$; then

$$A\triangle B=A\triangle (A\triangle C')=(A\triangle A)\triangle C'=\varnothing\triangle C'=C'$$

and

$$A\triangle B=A\triangle (A\triangle C)=(A\triangle A)\triangle C=\varnothing\triangle C=C\;,$$

so $C'=A\triangle B=C$, and $C$ is unique.